# Any site which offers interactive experience with GNU/Linux Desktop environments?

Tags: linux, debian, virtual-machine, desktop-environment

2-3 years ago, I had come across a site which offered remote/live interaction with different desktop environments.

These were self-contained default desktops and you as a user could get a feel of how the desktop environment behaved. This was designed at newbies/new users. Does anybody either know what I'm talking about or know of a similar service.

They probably used some sort of virtualizaiton to do this. Does anybody know ?